# Best way to detect if WIF runtime is installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, wif

A few pages of my ASP.Net app connect directly to another service using WIF.   WIF is just making inroads here, and while it is installed on the Test and Production servers, every time a new programmer or tester gets latest and happens to hit those pages without the WIF run-time installed on their machine, he gets a YSOD and an error about not finding Microsoft.IdentityModel ... which they don't ever read and instead fire off an IM telling me my app is broken.

I'd like to detect if the WIF runtime is installed and show a every helpful error message and link to the download page if not.   I don't want to check for a specific .dll path as this might change... and there are already different paths for 3.5 and 4.0.

Is there a best way to detect if the WIF run-time is installed?

(obviously in a page that doesn't reference it already... which would not display correctly without it installed)

**Edit**

It looks like [WIF is included in the framework with 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2012/03/15/windows-identity-foundation-in-the-net-framework-4-5-beta-tools-samples-claims-everywhere.aspx) so a 3.5/4.0 specific approach would be fine.  It won't be necessary to be future-proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try loading the Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll from the GAC inside a try/catch -block or better yet, just catch the specific exception users without the WIF runtime are currently getting and just use that to redirect the users to a specific error page/message.

To answer your exact question - is there a way to detect if the proper WIF installation package is present: if your application can access the registry (in a read-only mode at least), it's also possible to check if Windows Identity Foundation related items appear in SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Identity Foundation (and the associated Wow6432Node for 64-bit systems).

Comment: As only a few pages require WIF I want to check as soon as the app starts up and let them know long before they get to those pages that the app is missing a required component.   We don't do any fancy deployment packaging so there is not installer to do this job.

Comment: This registry check is all that other Microsoft installers do (I dissected several of them).  See my answer below for the code I ended up with.

Answer (score 3):

Official comment of microsoft:

```
Q: Under what registry key is WIF installed?
A: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsIdentityFoundation\setup\v3.5\.
```

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748487.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I went with the registry check suggestion from the answer above after examining some installers from Microsoft to see how they detected the presence of the WIF runtime, and that is all they do.

Here is what I went with:

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines if WIF is installed on the machine.
/// </summary>
public static class WifDetector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating that WIF appears to be installed.
    /// </summary>
    public static bool WifInstalled { get; private set; }

    static WifDetector()
    {
        WifInstalled = IsWifInstalled();
    }

    private static bool IsWifInstalled()
    {
        try
        {
            //return File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
            //                                "Reference Assemblies\\Microsoft\\Windows Identity Foundation\\v3.5\\Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll"));
            //The registry approach seems simpler.
            using( var registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows Identity Foundation") ?? 
                                     Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows Identity Foundation") )
            {
                return registryKey != null;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //if we don't have permissions or something, this probably isn't a developer machine, hopefully the server admins will figure out the pre-reqs.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the basepage or masterpage I check the value, and let the user know.  The actual checking is only performed once in the type-initializer, after that it is just simple static property access.

```
    private void CheckWifInstallation()
    {
        if (!WifDetector.WifInstalled)
        {
            var alert = new ClientSideAlert(
                    "This application requires the Windows Identity Foundation runtime to be installed on the webserver:\n");
            alert.AddMessageLine("Please install the appropriate WIF runtime for this operating system by visiting:\n");
            alert.AddMessageLine("http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17331 \n");
            alert.AddMessageLine("or simply search for 'WIF runtime install'\n");
            alert.AddMessageLine("Thanks, and have a nice day!'");
            alert.Display(Page);
        }
    }
```

We don't have fancy web deployment packages for developer machines, it is just get from source and go.   This will allow developers without this library to not waste time when they encounter a YSOD and an obscure assembly loading error.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can bundle WIF libraries with your app.
2. You can use WebPI and reference WIF SDK there.
3. Maybe if you try to load assembly from GAC will do the trick. [Reflection Only Assembly Loading](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/08/24/219691.aspx)